# Systemverilog $change Assertion

Tags: system-verilog

What would be the format if I didn't want data to change when the accept signal is low using $change? Would that be the most useful function?

Comment: As far as I get the question, you want data to be stable when accept is low. One can use `( (!accept) |-> ($stable(data) )`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The format of what? What "accept signal"? Are you asking for an example assertion that uses `$change`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a concurrent assertion, like for example:

```
assert property (!Accept |-> !($changed(Data)));
```